# How to adda array mutablearray attribute in coredata and fetching?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

```
How to add array of string into a specific attribute of a record?
```

i have a person entity with attributes useriD, name, phoneNumber and booksLiked. i want to insert booknames into "booksLiked" attribute of particular person. i dont know how to declare bookLiked(is it transformable?) and how to insert new book names.Later i want to retrieve all books name for a particular person.(swift) please help. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways you can achieve that:

- You can declare a "Binary Data" attribute and convert your NSArray to NSData using NSKeyedArchiver, and when you fetch it you then reconvert it using NSKeyedUnarchiver. (not recommended)
- You can create another managed object Liked Book and then set a one to many relationship in your model, so when you regenerate your NSManagedObject subclass you will have an NSSet reference held in likedBooks property and you can add books there using the predefined methods which should be automatically created in "Person" managed object subclass.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

Here you have an example of how you xcdatamodel file should look like:

[image]

[image]

Set the relationships properly and than make sure you set their inverse as shown for each one (on both entities). Make sure you select Delete rule: Cascade for the person to likedbook relationship so that all books for that person are deleted when the person is deleted. Also set that relationship "To Many" in order to be able to add multiple liked books in your NSSet. (just like in the pictures).

Now you have to to Editor menu in Xcode and choose create NSManagedObjectSubclass, select your entities based on which and you should have both classes created after this step.

Comment: thanks for your answer. i will try both methods.actually i dont know how to do second method.. want to research. do you have any sample code?

Comment: I will shortly edit my answer with what I can show you about how the model  looks like so you can get an idea on how you should create your relationship and your managed object subclasses